# protobuf 3.0.0 in xcode with error: thread-local storage is unsupported for the current targe

Tags: objective-c, xcode, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use `protobuf` 3.0.0 in my objective-c project, when I compile the `protobuf` project, there shows an error :

> "thread-local storage is unsupported for the current target."

because `protobuf` uses "__thread" in the code, maybe the `xcode` compiler do not support this character.

could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: please check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791060/c-thread-local-storage-clang-503-0-40-mac-osx

Comment: @aBilal17 So the answer is to ensure you use `libc++` instead of `libstdc++`?

Answer (score 0):

the protobuf source code is compiled as c++ in xcode,

here is my settings:

```
Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language:
C Language Dialect    GNU99 [-std=gnu99]
Compile Source As     According To File Type


Apple LLVM 6.0 Language - C++:
C++ Language Dialect   GNU++[-std=gnu++11]
C++ standard Library   libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with c++11 support)
```

here is the setting link:
[xcode setting snap](http://t3.qpic.cn/mblogpic/ad7e8fa3f0a8d5d7d300/2000)

Comment: No joy here. Still getting that issue, although its LLVM 9.0  now