# Clang targets: thread-local storage is not supported

Tags: multithreading, macos, clang, thread-local-storage, compiler-options

There are several questions about compiler options. Now I use the following:

```
-target i386-windows-gnu -mno-sse -c -O3
-target x86_64-windows-gnu -mcx16 -c -O3
-target i386-linux-gnu -mno-sse -c -O3
-target x86_64-linux-gnu -mcx16 -c -O3
-target i386-darwin-gnu -mno-sse -fomit-frame-pointer -c -O3
-target x86_64-macos-gnu -fomit-frame-pointer -c -O3
-target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -fPIC -c -O3
-target aarch64-linux-android -c -O3
-target armv7m-none-ios-gnueabi -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -c -O3
-target arm64-darwin-gnu -fno-stack-protector -c -O3
```

There are no complaints only on Linux/Android. For other platforms it gives a warning (https://godbolt.org/z/YhZ5uc):

```
clang-9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--gcc-toolchain=/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Compiler returned: 0
```

ARM32 platforms do not support the preserve_most attribute (https://godbolt.org/z/SQRJB2):

```
<source>:2:21: warning: 'preserve_most' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
void __attribute__((preserve_most)) proc_most(int* x);
```

But the biggest problem is that Mac/iOS does not support TLS variables (https://godbolt.org/z/6bqjby)!

```
__thread int x;

int test()
{
    return x;
}


<source>:2:1: error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current target
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791060/c-thread-local-storage-clang-503-0-40-mac-osx).

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18356

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention. But I already googled the answer to my question. And I got the impression that the problem was not solved. Could you take my link to the Godbolt (https://godbolt.org/z/6bqjby) and fix it so that TLS support is there? In addition, I also asked about warnings and the preserve_most attribute. Please pay attention to them too!

Comment: Are you writing new code? or are you porting old code that already uses TLS? I would avoid TLS in any new project: TLS is mainly useful for data that has `static` extent, and I try to avoid static data whenever possible. In new code, I would put any per-thread data into a `struct`, and I would give each thread a pointer to it's own private instance of the struct.

Comment: Hello. I am writing a low-level code (memory manager). I really need TLS.

Comment: Hello, having written low-level code for memory management extending from bare metal through caching kernel and base user space, I will stake the claim: using TLS is almost always a hack to correct a poor design or implementation.  Clear thinking always rids the design of TLS.  A great anti-pattern is in clang-blocks -- if the completion is ever executed after the thread that registered it has exitted the program panics.  Yet the closure is in no way associated with the thread that registers it.

Comment: Also, maybe the issue is godbolt; on my macos (16.7.0)  clang-900.0.39.2, your snippet compiles just fine; it even generates different code [ movq _x@TLVP(%rip), %rdi; callq *(%rdi))] vs [ movq _x@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax] if I omit the __thread hackery.